# How to extract specific strings from a Page url on Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I am new into google data studio and I would like to extract the first parameter and last parameter of the following url /red-car/2020.75/it-it/window. Therefore, being able to have one category for the car colour (red-car) and one for the region (it-it).

The position of these parameters will be always the same. Is there any way I could extract these?

I have tried to use regex expression but at the moment I was not able to figure out the right way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

get the first field (red-car):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(test,r"^[^/]*/([^/]+)")
```

or if the field contains `http://`;

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(REPLACE(test,"http://","") ,r"^[^/]*/([^/]+)")
```

get the 3rd field (region: it-it):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(test,r"^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]+)")
```

The `r"` stands for a regular expression. The round brackets are for the text to be extracted. `[^/]*` stands for any text without a slash.

See documentation: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487?hl=en&ref_topic=7041728